# Adiabatic theorem and the sudden sliding of an object on a plane with friction when tilted beyond some angle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, friction

Suppose a, say, rectangular object is on a plane with friction, and the temperature is at absolute zero and the combined system is in their quantum mechanical ground state. When the plane tilts a little bit, the object will stay still due to static friction. But when the tilt exceeds some angle, no matter how slowly the tilt changes, the object will suddenly start to slide. But on the other hand, the adiabatic theorem in quantum mechanics says that: a physical system remains in its instantaneous eigenstate if a given perturbation is acting on it slowly enough and if there is a gap between the eigenvalue and the rest of the Hamiltonian's spectrum. If the adiabatic theorem applies here, the object-plane system should always remain in their combined ground state, with no sudden sliding happening. So is the above sudden sliding due to a break of the adiabatic theorem, or that the spectrum is always gapless in such scenarios and thus the adiabatic theorem does not apply?
[image]

[image]

Comment: What does quantum mechanics have to do with static friction?

Comment: @BobD I think that is a very good and valuable question and I don't know the answer to your question yet, and I think it is also part of my question. I am just saying that it seems that the adiabatic theorem in quantum mechanics potentially has something to say about this object-on-a-tilting-plane phenomenon involving static friction, which could be contradictory to common experiences.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to understand the quantum adiabatic theorem intuitively?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/584308/).

Comment: It's not clear to me how you could model a situation with static friction in quantum mechanics, given that you can't even do it with a classical Hamiltonian.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I think that is a great and very interesting point! I didn't know that one cannot even model static friction with a classical Hamiltonian. This made me think about what is actually potentially interesting in my question. Please allow me to say a few more words about what I find interesting about the question I raised. Since the adiabatic theorem is not expected to break down, the sudden sliding seems to mean that the quantum mechanical spectrum is always continuous in such scenarios involving static friction as in my question. This seems to be a quite non-trivial conclusion.